# Jar file doesn't load prolog

Tags: java, prolog

In Netbeans it runs well but when i try to run it from jar file it doesn't load Prolog and stops there.  The code i am using is:

```
Term consult_arg[] = {
    new Atom("C://Users//dmpasd//Documents//NetBeansProjects//Anemia//src//anemia//new.pl")
};
Query consult_query
        = new Query(
                "consult",
                consult_arg);

boolean consulted = consult_query.hasSolution();

if (!consulted) {
    System.err.println("Consult failed");
    System.exit(1);

}
```

My next step was to change the newAtom to

```
new Atom(Diagnosis.class.getResource("new.pl").getPath())
```

but still nothing.

Comment: you have checked classpath contains all you need when running from .jar?

Comment: It has  the main.java as main.class nothing else.. The new file exists as "new.pl "

Comment: As described in http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/installation.html you'll need jpl.jar, jpl.dll and jpl.pl setup correctly. My best guess is you're missing jpl.jar from your classpath. Try running java -cp .:path\to\jpl.jar main

Comment: Jpl exists but outside from gui.jar file..

Comment: can you share how you call your class?

Comment: In netbeans works correctly..only in executable .jar  i have this problem..

Comment: It is the code above.. If you mean this.. This code is attached to a jbutton...

Comment: in netbeans the jpl.jar is already included in your runtime environment (otherwise it wouldn't even compile) but not so if your start as a (executable) jar. How do you run it?

Comment: No, I meant the command line for starting your jar.

Comment: For me i run it from netbeans but it's a school project and they will run it as exe

Comment: as .exe? How so? It's still java... First step: Make it run from .cmd then adjust your .jar manifest and/or make fat jar to include jpl.jar. It would be easy to run as yourproject.cmd though

Comment: so just a double click? Then no wonder jpl.jar is not found...

Comment: I'll try that and i let you know..Thank you.. :))

Comment: Haha..Ok....I am new in programming..^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have this directory layout:

```
YourProject/
YourProject/gui.jar
YourProject/lib/jpl.dll
YourProject/lib/jpl.jar
YourProject/lib/jpl.pl
YourProject/lib/libpl.dll
```

Then you could create

```
YourProject/startme.cmd
```

With the following contents:

```
REM @ECHO OFF
cd %CD%
java -Djava.library.path=.\lib\ -classpath gui.jar;lib\jpl.jar -jar gui.jar
pause
```

Now start *that* and see what happens.

Comment: Check my edits (changed cmd to give more output), run again and edit your question to show output please.

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.jpl7.PrologException: PrologException
: error(existence_error(source_sink, 'file:/C:/Users/dmpasd/Desktop/Anemia/Anemi
a.jar!/anemia/new.pl'), _0)
        at org.jpl7.Query.get1(Query.java:308)
        at org.jpl7.Query.hasMoreSolutions(Query.java:238)
        at org.jpl7.Query.oneSolution(Query.java:659)
        at org.jpl7.Query.hasSolution(Query.java:718)`


etc..

Comment: Well... thats up to you then - its a prolog exception, so prolog subsystem is now active.

Comment: Is anemia/new.pl included in your jar?

Comment: Ok...the problem was in 

 `new Atom(Diagnosis.class.getResource("new.pl").getPath())`